# "Problem occurred when checking for updates" and now I can't use terminal

Tags: update-manager, gnome-terminal

I believe my internet briefly cut out while I was downloading an update and screwed something up.

When my update finished the update-notifier told me "a problem occurred when checking for updates."

I tried to show updates but the button isn't working. I have also tried to open terminal to run sudo apt-get update but terminal won't open.

Everything else seems to be working fine.

Any ideas on how to re download the update without using terminal?

EDIT: All the below suggestions haven't fixed the problem. I am going to reinstall ubuntu tonight most likely.

Answer (score 2):

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, login to console and run there

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: I should give you an upvote :)

Comment: This didn't work :( 
I still have a “Problem occurred when checking for updates” and my terminal still won't show up.

Comment: @user2327814 why should this not work? You have asked for a terminal. tty1 is a terminal.

Comment: @user2327814 Can you post full error message?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. I was able to go into tty1, successfully run the apt-get commands, and get back out. I then restarted my computer and nothing seemed to change. I still get the  “Problem occurred when checking for updates” prompt and can't open the gnome-terminal.

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` in tty1.

Comment: @Pilot6 The full error is "A problem occurred when checking for the update" I see this error message from a red circle with a minus sign in it located in my task manager. I don't know of a more detailed way to view the error.

Comment: Trying to reinstall ubuntu-desktop did not fix the issue.

Comment: OK. Run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-terminal`.

Comment: Are there any errors when you run `sudo apt-get update` in tty?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26449/discussion-between-user2327814-and-pilot6).

Answer (score 0):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> is your home ticket
2. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to tty1
3. Login and make your updates
4. Use your home ticket ;)

Comment: Who is downvoting and why?

Comment: @Pilot6 Maybe the rainy day today :)