# Gnome terminal won't open except from file explorer

Tags: command-line, python, gnome-terminal, python3

When I try to open the terminal from the favorites bar it shows that it's loading but never opens. The good news is that it opens from the file explorer "Open in Terminal".

I recently updated my python to 3.9 following some online instructions. I installed python 3.9 and used:

`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 1`

`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.9 2`

This is the output of `sudo update-alternatives --config python3`

```
Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/python3.9   2         auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/python3.8   1         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.9   2         manual mode
```

I also tried to configure the gnome-terminal to use it by updating:

#!/usr/bin/python3

to this

#!/usr/bin/python3.9

It did not work so I thought maybe if rebooted the changes would take effect, and they did by giving me a whole set of booting issues that took me a good time to fix long story short I reinstalled the gui (because for some reason after the booting issue, this was next) and now I'm back to square one...

Please help, I won't mess with what I don't know anymore.

Comment: You may install other Python versions, but don't replace the system version.  As you have discovered, that breaks things.  Try setting your update-alternatives back to 3.8.

Comment: After opening the terminal from file explorer, does running `gnome-terminal` open another new terminal? ... If, yes, then the issue is just a broken favorite's link ... delete the old one and pin the running terminal's icon to the bar instead ... Please also see this similar post to know why this happened: [Terminal and other apps suddenly won't open](https://askubuntu.com/q/1448702)