# Need help with opening Software updater, several apps don't open

Tags: suspend

I am a new Ubuntu user and have several apps that do not open + whenever I suspend, it doesn't wake up again, so I have to hard shutdown by holding the power button (I saw that maybe updating some drivers could help with this, but I cannot open the software/driver updater). I have installed a newer version of python but I do not know if that is the issue. I have an AMD graphics driver and am on a Asus Zenbook.

EDIT: Here is a picture of the python:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: A Screenshot please?(Press print screen)

Comment: I have added a screenshot of python, what else do you need?

Comment: First the screen shot does not help at all. Second you need to re install. You killed the OS. Ubuntu needs the version of python to always be the one it shipped with. As you have experienced you can not use things as they need that version of python you no longer have. There are ways to have multiple versions of python installed and not affect the original and that is not what you did.

Comment: You also need to add the version of Ubuntu you are using.

Comment: Ah okay, the ubuntu version is 22.04, how do I reset to the original python version and remove the wrong ones?

Comment: As I said you re install.

Comment: You have to reinstall Ubuntu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Terminal and other apps suddenly won't open](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1448702/terminal-and-other-apps-suddenly-wont-open)

Comment: You installed a custom version of Python - no released Ubuntu version uses Python `3.11.0rc1`. Modifying the Python version will not end well, as is evident by a large amount of questions here.

Comment: I have reinstalled ubuntu now and upgraded to 22.10, but I still have suspend issues where it can't wake up after second suspend. I have tried many of the different fixes that are here, but none seem to work.

Comment: Try using a different kernel

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** From the comments in this thread, it sounds as if you may have resolved your issue with Python version complications, but you still have an issue with using suspend. If this is the case, you should create a new question, and keep that question limited and focused to just one topic: it's much easier to troubleshoot and solve your problems in this way. Thanks