# Archives directory /var/cache/apt/archives/partial is missing

Tags: command-line, apt, python

I am trying to install a python version on linux. But I am getting the following error:

```
Archives directory /var/cache/apt/archives/partial is missing
```

I have tried to create the file by :

```
mkdir -p /var/cache/apt/archives/partial
```

But i am getting the following:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/cache/apt’: File exists
```

Edit:

```
ls -l /var/cache/apt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Apr 17 20:00 /var/cache/apt -> /media/{dir_of_mounted_disc}/apt
```

How can I solve this?? Thank you!

Comment: Please add the output of `ls -l /var/cache/apt` ... It appears to be a symlink to a directory which is not normal ... What have you done? :-)

Comment: @Raffa I edited as you request.

Comment: It's indeed a symlink ... Remove it with `sudo rm /var/cache/apt` ... Then recreate the directory structure with `sudo mkdir -p /var/cache/apt/archives/partial`  ... And see if that works ... However "*I am trying to install a python version on linux*" worries me that this is the least of your proplems

Comment: seems like it worked!! thank you so much!! @Raffa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `/var/cache/apt` is a symlink to a directory ... Which is not normal ... Remove it with:

```bash
sudo rm /var/cache/apt
```

Then recreate the directory structure with:

```bash
sudo mkdir -p /var/cache/apt/archives/partial
```

However:

> "I am trying to install a python version on linux"

worries me that this is the least of your problems ... Please be careful not to change/remove system python version ... See for example:

[Terminal and other apps suddenly won't open](https://askubuntu.com/q/1448702)