# /lib is usually a softlink, but was replaced by a mostly empty directory

Tags: apt, python3

I have an Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS server.

1. It suddenly started refusing ssh connections citing `/bin/bash: No such file or directory`.
2. Reboot the machine fails with a kernel panic, with the following excerpts:

```
Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ... mkdir: can't create directory '/root/lib/modules': Read-only file system
[...]
run-init: can't execute '/sbin/init', No such file or directory
[...]
run-init, can't execute '/etc/init': Permission denied
[...]
Kernel panic not syncing: Attempted to kill Init! exitcode-Ox00000100`
```

3. Booting from a live USB, and looking inside the root disk. `/sbin/init` is not missing but it is a softlink and the `/lib/systemd/systemd` it points to is missing. This leads me to find out that `/lib` is a directory containing only a `x86_64-linux-gnu` folder, while in other machines, `/lib` is usually a softlink to `usr/lib`
4. After backing up `/lib` and replacing it with a softlink to `usr/lib`, I am now able to reboot and ssh into the machine!
5. However, when trying to run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` to make sure my packages are in order, I am now faced with these errors that make apt fail:

```
/usr/bin/python3: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.35' not found (required by /usr/bin/python3)
/usr/bin/python3: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /usr/bin/python3)
/usr/bin/python3: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /usr/bin/python3)
/usr/bin/python3: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /usr/bin/python3)
```

How may I recover the system in this situation, short of re-installing Ubuntu?
Also, what may have caused this situation?

### Edit 1:

Here is the content of the `x86_64-linux-gnu` I found at `/lib` originally. I don't think it contains as many files as it's supposed to

```
$ ls [...]/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
libexpat.so.1  libexpat.so.1.8.7  libhistory.so.8  libhistory.so.8.1  libreadline.so.8  libreadline.so.8.1

$ diff [...]/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu | grep -v "Only in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"
Binary files [...]/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 and /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 differ
Only in [...]/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu: libexpat.so.1.8.7
Binary files [...]/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhistory.so.8 and /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhistory.so.8 differ
Only in [...]/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu: libhistory.so.8.1
Binary files [...]/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.8 and /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.8 differ
Only in [...]/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu: libreadline.so.8.1
```

Also, these warnings also show up just when I SSH in:

```
/usr/bin/xauth: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /usr/bin/xauth)
/usr/bin/xauth: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /usr/bin/xauth)
/usr/bin/xauth: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6)
/usr/bin/xauth: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6)
/usr/bin/xauth: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6)
/usr/bin/xauth: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0)
/usr/bin/xauth: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmd.so.0)
```

Comment: For that one, try copying the directory `x86_64-linux-gnu` that you backed up from `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`  assuming you have previously moved it from its original location and it's still intact ... You seem to have messed up your filesystem hierarchy quiet a bit.

Comment: AFAIK Ubuntu 20.04 uses libc version 2.31 - so it suggests your /usr/bin/python3 is not the default version from the Ubuntu repo?

Comment: @Raffa, I just edited the question to add more details on the contents of the `x86_64-linux-gnu` I backed up. I don't think it has everything it's supposed to, and the few packages still in it don't seem to relate to the warnings.

Comment: @steeldriver I think you're right. Any way I could downgrade all packages to their default versions in Ubuntu repo, or install a higher version of `libc` & `libm` to match what is now being required? All without being able to use `apt`?

Comment: @steeldriver, by the way, I can see `/usr/bin/python3 -> python3.10` and there is a `python3.8` available there. Maybe I could try redirecting `/usr/bin/python3` to 3.8?

Comment: This related post might help: [Terminal and other apps suddenly won't open](https://askubuntu.com/q/1448702)

Comment: @LemmeTestThat yes re-linking `/usr/bin/python3` to `python3.8` should help

Comment: @steeldriver Linking `python3.8` did seem to get apt going further, but then It still crashed with an error from `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0`