# I am able to login but, can't authinticate! why?

Tags: software-installation, password, update-manager, password-recovery

Well, I am a Python developer working on object-oriented programming with data science in cybersecurity. In this operation, for some reason (better not to say), I switched the operating system.

The problem is:

I am able to login to Ubuntu but can't authenticate when installing software, updating Ubuntu, or editing files.
I am 100% sure that I typed the correct password; in fact, I can't update Ubuntu because authentication is not working properly.I have read so much about how to fix this problem but
I didn't get any appropriate answers.
Even though I can't open the terminal, when I click on the terminal icon, it shows loading but never loads; in fact, I have tried the hot key (control + alt + T), but it didn't work.
So that I can't install any software or update Ubuntu.Neither reset my password.

What I have tried:

I have reinstalled a fresh of Ubuntu image four times (Ubuntu LTS 22.04 Jammy Jellyfish 64-bit)
I have attended the unattended installation on VirtualBox.

what I think the problem is

Comment: Have you altered the system Python version? ... See for example: [Terminal and other apps suddenly won't open](https://askubuntu.com/q/1448702)

Comment: Please be clear with details; you mention 22.04 & *jammy jellyfish* so thank you, but 64-bit is unclear as there are multiple 64-bit architectures, ie. *amd64*, *ppc64el*, *arm64*, *riscv64*...  however as only ARM cpus have 32bit + 64bit option maybe you mean *arm64* ??   I suspect this isn't so  (x86 32-bit ended with *disco* or 19.04).  64-bit is only helpful if you say which 64-bit.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "authenticate". The login process is the "authentication". The second part would be "Authorization". Do you mean "authorization for installing software" ? can you provide error messages or a screenshot. I guess you do not have "sudo" rights.

Comment: the version is 19.04

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 is EOL or *end-of-life* (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/01/23/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-23-2020/) thus off-topic on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) unless your question is specific to help moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Use a LTS or *long-term-support* release if you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades