# How can I fix the numerous issues that came from removing python

Tags: 20.04, python3

I have Ubuntu 20.04. Recently I removed Python version 3.8.10 and reinstalled it while trying to get an Wemos board to work. It didn't succeed in the end, but that's not what's important right now.

After I removed Python a lot of default applications, such as text editor, image viewer and terminal disappeared. I reloaded the terminal from Ubuntu store, but couldn't find the default text editor. So I replaced it with gedit, but it doesn't have an access to my other locale aside from the main computer, while the original text editor did.

On top of that, my desktop icons disappeared, although the folder with the files are still in the directory.

This is a rather large bundle of issues so I'm not certain at all how to start fixing them. Should I address them individually or try some large-scale solution, such as updating to 22? What would the potential risks in updating the whole OS be?

Comment: The quickest method: reinstall without formatting.

Comment: ... Or try reinstalling ubuntu-desktop with `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` ... If it doesn't work from your current system, then do it from a live system: https://askubuntu.com/a/1448819